# Restoration of GlobalKTables is extremely slow

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Since we introduced GlobalKTables in streams in several services, the startup time of the services grew to unbearable amounts of time. We have a listener observing the state of state store restoration and this is what stands in the logs:

```
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-4
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Seeking to offset 4 for partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-4
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreStart for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-4
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - started state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, remaining partitions: 1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreEnd for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-4
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - finished state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Seeking to offset 1 for partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreStart for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - started state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, remaining partitions: 1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreEnd for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - finished state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-6
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Seeking to offset 1 for partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-6
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreStart for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-6
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - started state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, remaining partitions: 1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreEnd for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-6
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - finished state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-7
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Seeking to offset 1 for partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-7
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreStart for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-7
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - started state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, remaining partitions: 1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreEnd for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-7
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - finished state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-3
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-global-consumer, groupId=null] Seeking to offset 4 for partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-3
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - onRestoreStart for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, partition wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-3
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - started state restore for store wrwks-bef-equipmenttyp-aggregat-privat-1-STATE-STORE-0000000005, remaining partitions: 1
[wrwks-bef-projekt-export-projektAggregate-5e88016d-ae03-49fe-80b0-46c2238f528d-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  a.w.b.p.h.StreamAndStateStoreStateListener - publishing availability information: liveness false, readiness false
```

This topic consists of 20 records and the bootstrap time is several minutes *if* it completes. In other cases it doesn't complete at all which leads to repeated restarts by the k8s watchdog after a wait time of 5 minutes in our cluster.

A very annoying workaround is to delete the state store directory and restart the service, then the service usually starts within a reasonable amount of time.

This behaviour applies to all services using GlobalKTables. All services use Kafka Streams via Spring Cloud Stream 2021.0.5.

Comment: I don't see how Spring may interfere with `GlobalKTable,` which causes it to slow down. I feel this same issue will occur if you use Kafka Streams directly. I am curious to hear if there is anything that we can do to improve the situation from Kafka Streams itself.

Comment: @sobychacko I'm currently also only trying to narrow down the problem space, that's why I applied spring tags too.

Comment: What Kafka Streams versions is used under the hood? There is one known issue for global-state stores which sound similar, that is fixed in Kafka 3.2.0 release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14713

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax In the meantime both, the services (to Spring Cloud 2022.0.1 with Kafka Streams 3.3.2) as well as the brokers (Kafka 3.0.1) have been upgraded and thus the issue vanished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime both, the services (to Spring Cloud 2022.0.1 with Kafka Streams 3.3.2) as well as the brokers (Kafka 3.0.1) have been upgraded and thus the issue vanished.